# Spring context initialization even on JNDI error

Tags: java, spring, jndi

I have Spring configuration below. How I can make Spring content initialization even if DB_JNDI does not exist in Application server?

```
 <jee:jndi-lookup id="friends.db" jndi-name="DB_JNDI"/>

    <bean name="friendsDbDaoImpl" class="com.tims.db.friendsDbDaoImpl" init-method="init" >
        <property name="dataSource" ref="friends.db" />
        <property name="queryTimeout" value="${imos.db.friends.querytimeout}" />
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Spring profiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html). They were implemented with this kind of requirement (conditional configuration) in mind.

Comment: in that case I will get initialization error right, @Component
public class XXXService {

   //@Resource
   private FriendsDbDaoImpl friendsDbDaoImpl;
   
   }

Comment: You can load a friendsDbDaoImpl configured with friends.db datasource with one profile and avoid loading that bean when that profile is not active

Comment: How I can avoid context initialization when annotation based one is used?

Comment: Can you please rephrase? I couldn't understand.

Comment: think about that when I use a profile and in this profile I am using different applicationcontext.xml with lack of  DB_JNDI definition. In that case annotated friendsDbDaoImpl class in XXXService  class causes an error. right?

Comment: You can use a single applicationContext.xml with multiple profiles. Given this, your beans should be able to handle different situations. To answer your question, yes, unless you specify `required = false` as `@Autowired` attribute (assuming that you are using Spring annotations or their equivalent in the XML configuration)